# Postfix disable error email notifications

Tags: postfix

I'm trying to disable Postfix error email notifications. I do not want to receive notification emails whenever a "User is unknown in virtual mailbox table".

I still want to receive bounce notifications.

main.cf :

```
notify_classes = bounce
bounce_notice_recipient = bounce@example.com
```

After restarting Postfix, I'm still receiving these emails
(sent to postmaster - not bounce).

Any ideas how to fix this? I'm receiving a lot of notification emails from spammers sending emails to non-existent addresses.

```
Postfix SMTP server: errors from example.com[​11.22.33.44]

Transcript of session follows.

Out: 220 example.com ESMTP Postfix (3.2.0)
In:  EHLO whatever.com
Out: 250-example.com
Out: 250-PIPELINING
Out: 250-SIZE 50000000
Out: 250-ETRN
Out: 250-STARTTLS
Out: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
Out: 250-8BITMIME
Out: 250-DSN
Out: 250 SMTPUTF8
In:  STARTTLS
Out: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
In:  EHLO whatever.com
Out: 250-example.com
Out: 250-PIPELINING
Out: 250-SIZE 50000000
Out: 250-ETRN
Out: 250-AUTH PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 LOGIN
Out: 250-AUTH=PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 LOGIN
Out: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
Out: 250-8BITMIME
Out: 250-DSN
Out: 250 SMTPUTF8
In:  MAIL FROM:<spammer@spam.com> SIZE=2110
Out: 250 2.1.0 Ok
In:  RCPT TO:<asdfasdf@example.com>
Out: 550 5.1.1 <asdfasdf@example.com>: Recipient address rejected: User
  unknown in virtual mailbox table
In:  RSET
Out: 250 2.0.0 Ok
In:  QUIT
Out: 221 2.0.0 Bye
```

Comment: please add output of `postconf -n`

Comment: I would like too .. but I have no idea what is safe to post or not without exposing my mail server to all sorts of issues. I was hoping someone would just know the setting that is causing this issue.

Comment: You can at least check what is the actual value of `postconf |grep notify_classes`

Comment: [localhost ~]$ postconf | grep notify_classes
: notify_classes = bounce

Comment: I managed to solve the issue - see below for answer. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by adding this line to main.cf :

error_notice_recipient = blackhole@localhost

> error_notice_recipient (default: postmaster)
>
> The recipient of postmaster notifications about mail delivery problems
> that are caused by policy, resource, software or protocol errors.
> These notifications are enabled with the notify_classes parameter.

Then adding this line to /etc/aliases :

blackhole: /dev/null

Do not use this solution if your "notify_classes" line contains either policy, resource, software or protocol.